# What was the cartoon show around 2004-2007 in which a student at high school turned into a giant monster worm

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched this cartoon show around 2004-2007 in Hong Kong (it was probably a rerun of a show from the U.S. or U.K.) about teenagers in high school.

One of them got bit or cut or something and was pulsating or something in his bedroom. The show kept dramatically showing his DNA changing and him sweating as he began to turn.

At school later he became this massive worm with teeth where the head was. There was one point in the show when a group of teenagers were tracking the worm (the boy or someone else) and it bursts through a barn.

I watched this when I was around five or six and this gave me nightmares for weeks. It was similar to the worm in the movie series Dune.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.